# Let $S$ be the disk $|z|<3$ in the complex plane and let $f:S→\mathbb C$ be an analytic function such that $f(1+\frac{\sqrt2}{n}i)=-\frac{2}{n^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $S$ be the disk $|z|<3$ in the complex plane and let $f:S→\mathbb C$ be an analytic function such that $f(1+\frac{\sqrt2}{n}i)=-\frac{2}{n^2}$ for all natural numbers $n$.Then what is the value of $f(\sqrt{2})$?

I don't know how to move. so please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** At least for the countably many points specified, we have $f(z)=(z-1)^2$. Can you see why we must have $f(z)=(z-1)^2$ for all $z\in S$?

Comment: no Sir. plz explain. i am not very well in complex analysis.

Comment: Have you heard about the [Identity Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem)?

Comment: how do u applying identity theorem here?

Comment: $f(z)$ and $(z-1)^2$ agree on a set of points that has an accumulation point (namely $1$) that is an interior point o fthe domain. Since the domain is connected, we have equality on th ewhole domain.

Comment: Thank u very much Sir i got this very clearly.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen But the answer in my book is $3+2\sqrt 2$ when $z=\sqrt 2$ and according to our function answer should be $3-2\sqrt 2$